# Hidden Field in ListView Android?

Tags: android

I'm wondering if there is a way to hide a field in Android.
I tried with setting the value in a TextEdit and then making the TextEdit invisible, but the result is that the value is invisible, but the control takes space.

In my case, I want to store an extra value in a row of a ListView.
Is there another solution besides using hidden fields?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use View's `public static final int  GONE` field.

In your case `textEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, or in xml `android:visibility="gone"`

Setting the view to `INVISIBLE` does not take layout into consideration, but `GONE` does.

Answer (score 17):

View has methods `setTag()` and `getTag()` that you can use to associate some extra data with row of ListView. For example I'm using `CursorAdapter` class and in `newView()` and `bindView()` methods I call `view.setTag()`. Then in `OnItemClickListener` I call `view.getTag()`.

Comment: This is actually a much more relevant answer to this question.

Comment: From answers to related questions, this has two problems: One is that setting a tag means it's not obvious to other devs who may work on your code from looking at the XML what data is actually on the view. The other is that setTag accepts an int (or Object that needs to be cast) and can be overwritten elsewhere accidentally.

There seem to be two good answers here; one is the TextView as suggested here, though it does seem a bit hacky. The reason I use it instead of the alternative (custom XML attributes) is because what seems like the right way to do it is terribly convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the only invisible data contained by rows of ListView is `id` (long). I was also trying to find a way to pass some data (like `uuid`) to the row click handler, however seems a "GONE" TextView is the best solution for now...